# minifilter scanner in Windows 10 64 bit crashed the system after the installation

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I have successfully installed and run the minifilter scanner in Windows 10 32bit. But when I put it in Window 10 64bit, the windows crashed after restart. Are there any steps I need to do in the Windows configuration? I have tried to disable the checking of driver signature but the windows also crashed. Any idea?

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/scanner